# how to convert Array of UIImage to Array of base64 in swift 3 ?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, base64

I have an array of images in my codes that are [UIImage] but I want to convert them to base64 - I couldn't ! - I found similar questions but when I used their answers I received Fatal Error

```
for i in  0...tinyViewController.imageUpload.count - 1 {
        print(i)


        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tinyViewController.imageUpload[i] , 1)

        let base64String = (imageData! as Data).base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        print(base64String)

}
```

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function to convert each UIImage to base64 String. I used it in my project. It works perfect for me.

```
func base64(from image: UIImage) -> String? {
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        if let imageString = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed) {
            return imageString
        }
        return nil
    }
```

So, do this:

```
for i in  0...tinyViewController.imageUpload.count - 1 {
        print(i)

        print(base64(from: tinyViewController.imageUpload[i]))

}
```

Comment: this method will not execute because my images are in an array in a for loop and I should use them in this method but swift doesn't let me to use that ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Insert my function and change your code as I wrote.

Comment: Again I received fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Maybe the error in another place of your code? There is no force unwrapping in my code.

Comment: where should be the function that you write ? before loop or after loop or inside that?

Comment: It should be inside your class, but not inside the method where the loop is.

Comment: I used Break Point and this function will return nil - why?

Comment: It can happen because of invalid images.

Comment: the images are the images that taken by the camera in device and saved to the camera roll

Comment: Ok I found the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846705/uiimagepngrepresentationuiimage-returns-nil/#answer-28846787